# net core wsfed change realm on OnRedirectToIdentityProvider

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am trying to change realm inside of wsfed event. Reason for that is because client app can be called via different urls, and based on different urls I change template for partner:

```
  private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext redirectContext)
        {
            var url = redirectContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + redirectContext.Request.Host.Value + "/";
            redirectContext.Options.Wtrealm = url;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Authentication url is created with no issues, problem arises after log in, I get:

> SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation
>   failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match:
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable
>   audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters
>   validationParameters) in Validators.cs, line 108

Is it possible to change realm for client on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. TokenValidationParameters ValidAudience has to be updated as well.

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext redirectContext)
{
    var url = redirectContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + redirectContext.Request.Host.Value + "/";
    redirectContext.Options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = url
    };

    redirectContext.Options.Wtrealm = url;
    redirectContext.Options.SignOutWreply = url + "home/logout";

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Do not modify shared state like Options per request. It's not thread safe and you will affect the behavior of other requests.

Comment: What would be better solution?

Comment: Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/pull/44